# session timeout in php code and in htaccess?

Tags: php

What we use to set the session time out in php. I found following:

```
ini_set(session.cookie_lifetime, 3600);
ini_set(session.gc_maxlifetime, 3600);
```

Is it right way to set timeout for session in php? Or is there any way we can set the time out in htaccess file?

Maybe its a simple question, but I am not really able to get the answer, even tried on SO, Google and php.net but no straight solutions or code for this.

Comment: If I'll add this to top of the page then will it set the session timeout every time?

Comment: Note that these do not really control a session’s lifetime (see *[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960)*).

Comment: I found that in php 5.2 that the above didnt work unless I added quotes around the values...

ie...

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '3600');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600');

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding following code in my `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    #Session timeout
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 1200
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the lifetime value to `0`

`session.cookie_lifetime 1200`

`session.cookie_lifetime` specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser.

## The value 0 means "until the browser is closed."

`session.gc_maxlifetime 1440`

`session.gc_maxlifetime` specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as "garbage" and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start