# Where do I place .htaccess with session timeout?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I have an .htaccess file with:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10
```

Where do I place the .htaccess file? In the directory of the session creation or in the directory of session start?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206061/session-timeout-in-php-code-and-in-htaccess>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206061/session-timeout-in-php-code-and-in-htaccess</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session timeout in php code and in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206061/session-timeout-in-php-code-and-in-htaccess)